# android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton stop working when add Facebook lib in project

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xml-layout

I am developing one app.My android studio version is 1.4. In my app I added `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` button when I am design. Its work fine before I add facebook lib. 
When I add facebook lib then float button stop working and it's UI will be changed and other thing is when I try to initialize then it's send me error `NullPointerException`. When I add facebook lib in my project then FlaotButton UI changed and it's look like this. 
[image]
and when i remove facebook lib from gradle file then it's look like this [image].
Thanks in advance and Help is very appreciated.

my app level **build.gradle** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zennaxx.socialgf"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

This is my **login_activity.xml** layout file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.zennaxx.socialgf.Login">

    <include layout="@layout/login_layout"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is my **login_layout.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">

            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="41dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgFacebook"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/right_side"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_facebook" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgGoogle"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_google_plus" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_w_h"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_w_h"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/hint_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Login Button -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_reset_password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_forgot_password"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <!-- Link to Login Screen -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_link_to_register"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Error Log

```
11-21 02:11:38.053 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #148: Binary XML file line #148: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
11-21 02:11:38.053 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
11-21 02:11:38.054 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
11-21 02:11:38.054 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
11-21 02:11:38.054 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
11-21 02:11:38.054 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
11-21 02:11:38.054 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at com.zennaxx.socialgf.Login.onCreate(Login.java:76)
11-21 02:11:38.054 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
11-21 02:11:38.054 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
11-21 02:11:38.054 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
11-21 02:11:38.054 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
11-21 02:11:38.054 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
11-21 02:11:38.055 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
11-21 02:11:38.055 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-21 02:11:38.055 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-21 02:11:38.055 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-21 02:11:38.055 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-21 02:11:38.055 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-21 02:11:38.055 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-21 02:11:38.055 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #148: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
11-21 02:11:38.055 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
11-21 02:11:38.056 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
11-21 02:11:38.056 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-21 02:11:38.056 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
11-21 02:11:38.056 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
11-21 02:11:38.056 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
11-21 02:11:38.056 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
11-21 02:11:38.056 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
11-21 02:11:38.056 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     ... 17 more
11-21 02:11:38.056 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-21 02:11:38.057 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
11-21 02:11:38.057 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
11-21 02:11:38.057 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     ... 24 more
11-21 02:11:38.057 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroid/widget/ImageView;Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatDrawableManager;)V in class Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper' appears in /data/app/com.zennaxx.socialgf-1/base.apk)
11-21 02:11:38.057 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:133)
11-21 02:11:38.057 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:110)
11-21 02:11:38.058 2309-2309/com.zennaxx.socialgf W/System.err:     ... 26 more
11-21 02:11:38.176 2309-2336/com.zennaxx.socialgf D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
11
```

Comment: can you post the error blog??

Comment: Post the exception

Comment: please see updated question my question

Comment: what is use floating button..

Comment: It used for when i click on that then open new activity no more

Answer (score 1):

I search on google and i have seen so many question about `FloatingActionButton` Inflating error as i faced. I search about facebook sdk then after know that Facebook library is conflicting my FloatActionButton, because in my project Facebook SDK library version is greater then my appcompat v7.
 I updated these which are as below 
 1. Android SDK Build Tools. 
 2. Android SDK Tools.
3. Android SDK Platform-Tools.
4.Google Play service.
5. Google Repository.
Now my compile library is like this with facebook sdk and it's work fine in my project.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```